# How can I record user agent and other information into a paragraph to be displayed on my webpage?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginning Javascript user, and I would like to include some technical functionality for visitors to the website I am building. This includes userAgent information. I have seen several solutions or partial solutions which for me, are not working. The code I am currently trying out is:

```js
let text = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>" +
  "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>" +
  "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>" +
  "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>" +
  "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>" +
  "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>" +
  "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>" +
  "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("userAgent").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="userAgent"></div>
```

I have an appropriately named paragraph called userAgent, but for some reason innerHTML is not recording text into the paragraph. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

You can disregard most of the HTML, but here it is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Papers</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id = "wrapper">
            <div id="one">
                <p>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div><p id="userAgent"></p></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder1"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder2"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder3"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder4"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder5"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder6"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder7"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder8"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder9"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder10"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder11"></div>
            <div id="image_placeholder12"></div>
            <div id="article1"></div>
        
        </div>
        <hr height="45px" width="100%">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Do you have an element that has an **id** of `userAgent`? This code works for me when I have an element with an id of `userAgent`.

Comment: It does work for me, most likely an issue with your userAgent element, either it does not exist or is not visible

Comment: I converted your code to a live demo and added the HTML that I assumed should be there bit which you omitted. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect HTML. I tried with both a <div> and a <p>.